# Get user Input and added to a list

Tags: haskell

The function buildTasksList take and empty list get the user input and return new list with the userInput added to it.

In the main function I am trying to create new list by doing `task ++ buildTasksList []` this approch give me this error

Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
Expected type: IO a0
Actual type: [a0]

```
task = []

printTasks [] = do
  putStrLn "That's all the tasks!"
printTasks (x : xs) = do
  putStrLn $ "  " ++ x
  printTasks xs

buildTasksList tasks = do
  putStrLn "Enter a task: "
  input <- getLine
  let task = input : tasks
  return task


main = do
  putStrLn "Below are the options: \nadd\nprint\nsearch"
  input <- getLine
  task ++ buildTasksList []
  main
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that your function buildTasksList is of type:

```
buildTasksList :: [String] -> IO [String]
```

while task is of type:

```
[a]
```

so you would need to take result of buildTasksList out of its context:

```
l_Tasks <- buildTasksList []
let newTasks = l_Tasks ++ task
return newTasks
```

Easing up your example and adding a ending option you could do something like:

```
main :: IO ()
main = main' []
    where
        main' :: [String] -> IO ()
        main' list = do
            putStrLn "Below are the options: \nadd\nprint\nsearch"
            putStrLn "Enter a task: "
            input <- getLine 
            correctInput input list

        correctInput :: String -> [String] -> IO ()
        correctInput input list
            | input == "add" || input == "print" || input == "search" 
                = main' $ input : list
            | input == "End" = printTasks list
            | otherwise = do
                putStrLn "wrong input"
                main' list
```